# Difference between two OpenId Connect implementation

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, openid-connect, mitreid-connect

Is there any functional difference between [Mitreid-Connect](http://kit.mit.edu/projects/mitreid-connect) implementation and [CAS support](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/OIDC-Authentication.html) of OpenId-Connect protocol?

Comment: It's quite interesting that https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/OIDC-Authentication.html does not list the UserInfo endpoint. I thought this is a mandatory endpoint (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo)

Comment: It's the same thing as the profile endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obvious difference between MitreId and CAS is that while MitreId only supports OpenID Connect, CAS supports CAS, SAML, OpenID and OpenID Connect.

Regarding the OpenID Connect protocol, MitreId has a broader support of OpenID Connect (I'm especially thinking of dynamic clients registration and the implicit flow) if you take a look at https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/OIDC-Authentication.html.

In most cases, it should not make any difference as the main flow is supported by CAS.

And hopefully the incoming CAS server version (May 2017) fills the missing gaps: https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/OIDC-Authentication.html

Comment: I always thought of CAS, SAML and OpenID-Connect protocols as competing protocols that only one of them should be picked for a particular use case.  
So, what is the intent of the [CAS project](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/index.html) to support all these protocols if one should only pick one of them?

Comment: These protocols are close, but some provide features others don't have (Javascript / web service authentication for example). But the main reason is that in the enterprise world, you never have only one protocol, but several protocols used for various reasons: vendor locked in software, legacy applications...